# Springboot + SQL Server + Mybatis Select queries are very slower

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, mybatis

I am using SpringBoot + SQL Server + Mybatis to fetch the data from tables.

**Data size :**

- Infotainment table - 360 million rows
- Graphics table - 200 million rows

Queries are running on SQL client well within 1 second, but when I integrate it with the SpringBoot + Mybatis it is taking too much time (more than 5 seconds).

application.yaml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1534;database=dev;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
    username: root
    password: root
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 50
      schema: INFOTAINMENT
          
mybatis:
  mapperLocations: classpath:config/mybatis/*.xml
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/infos")
public class APIController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(APIController.class);
    
    @Autowired
    InfoTainmentMapper mapper;
    
    @GetMapping
    public List<InfoTainment> findAll() {
        return mapper.findAll();
    }
}
```

InfotainMentMapper.java

```
@Mapper
public interface InfoTainmentMapper {
    @Select("<script>  
    "SELECT * from Infotainment i INNER JOIN Graphics g "+
    "ON i.id = g.info_id"+
    "WHERE i.info_in = #{infoin}"+
    </script>  ")
    @ResultMap("infoTainmentMapper")
    Optional<InfoTainment> findAll(@Param(value = "infoin")String infoin);
}
```

InfoTainment.java

```
@Data
class InfoTainment{
    private String description;
    private Double price;
    private String code;
}
```

XML Mapper

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
    
<mapper namespace='com.dev.mappers.InfoTainmentMapper'>
    <resultMap id="infoTainmentMapper" type="com.dev.domain.Infotainment">
        <result property="description" column="description"/>
        <result property="price" column="price"/> 
        <result property="code" column="code"/>
    </resultMap>   

</mapper>
```

Problem here is if i execute the same query on the SQL Server it is taking below 1 second. And same from application it is finish execution more than 5 seconds
.
Table level indexing already exist. and for this I am using `sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false` in connection string.
For my current scenario I am executing several queries in CompletableFuture block, and each is having same problem of latency. I tried to put replicate my problem here. but overall the same issue the Mybatis is giving me slow response.

Comment: You're not actually sending a parameter, you're just concatenating the value in. For SQL performance help, you should [edit] your question and provide the table and index definitions, and share a query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. I note that you are using the old-style `,` comma-join syntax, which was replaced 30 years ago

Comment: I guess I am parameterized the SQL query. and as this is a confidential data structures. So, I tried to cast this problem into different tables. I am sorry that couldn't add the query cost(since security concern). but I am assured that our DBA guy is verified this. and it is looks OK, it is the problem only with my application only.
could you please let me know where I am doing mistake of concatenate so, that I can rectify it.
@Charlieface thanx for your review I have modified the SQL part with JOINS, its my laziness that I have quickly typed the query in that.

Comment: `WHERE i.info_in = #{infoin}` looks like you are interpolating the query variable straight in to the query text but maybe I'm not reading that right

Comment: @Charlieface as this is as per similar ways of mybatis query param usages. although looks like concatenate . but this is absolutely parameterized query only.
I am referring to this tutorial. https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-iBatis-with-h2-tutorial

Comment: OK could be. Be that as it may, you need to provide the info I asked. You can anonymize the query plan with SentryOne Plan Explorer. I suggest you grab the query plan both from the cache and from SSMS, because it may be slighlty different from the application due to how the parameters are being passed (unicode, length, `SET` options etc)

Comment: Please consider that most of us not living in India will have no idea what are "crores rows". So please don't use Indian words here.

Comment: @JamesZ I am really sorry for not using universal abbreviations. I will take this care going forward. and thank you for updating the same in this question.